# ELMAH looking for binaries on Virtual director

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, elmah

I have a virtual directory just above the root of my web app that I use to store product images.

After I installed ELMAH for logging I realized images stopped working. This was due to ELMAH looking for its dll under productimages/bin folder.

After i created a bin dir and placed the dll images are now working

I don't like this as a long term solution though. Any idea why it is doing this and how to fix?

Answer (score 5):

The virtual directory inherits the configuration of your main application. To disable ELMAH in your virtual directory you need to add a web.config file to it with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
            <remove name="ErrorLog" />
            <remove name="ErrorMail" />
            <remove name="ErrorFilter" />
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="Elmah" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

(make sure the names match those of your modules/handlers in the main web.config file)

Answer (score -1):

You could use some URL re-writing to direct productimages\bin at \bin in your solution could you not?

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: Woudn't work - .NET tries to load the DLL via the file system, not via a URL.